# Figures aligned at top

Tags: floats

I have a document in overleaf with some text before a figure, however when it is compiled, the figure appears above the text, including the header. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I have the following packages active:

```
\usepackage{helvet} 
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear, style=apa]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, stackengine}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4, detect-display-math = true, detect-weight, detect-mode = true, math-rm, group-separator = {,} }
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{chngcntr} % IMPORTANT FOR THE NUMBERING OF SECTIONS AND EQUATIONS 
\usepackage{tikz} % SKETCHING PACKAGE
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\sloppy
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{svg} 
\usepackage[super]{nth}
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lscape} 
\usepackage{nomencl} 

\fancypagestyle{style1}{
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{} 
\fancyfoot[R]{Page \thepage \hspace{1pt} of \pageref{LastPage}}}
```

relevant document:

```
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}

\begin{document}
\section*{Introduction}
Xylenes are a class of highly useful chemical raw materials. Their chemical formulae are shown in Figure \ref{fig:xylene_strucutres}.

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includesvg[scale=0.43]{Introduction/Xylene_structures}
    \caption{Chemical formulae of p-xylene, o-xylene, and m-xylene}
    \label{fig:xylene_strucutres}
\end{figure}

P-xylene enjoys the largest market among the three isomers.




\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Unfortunately, the code you show isn't sufficient to answer your question.  The reason that a figure appears somewhere else than where it is input depends on *how* it is input.  We need to know what document class is used, whether you are using the `figure` environment (by definition a "float"), and whether you have specified any options.  (Most of the packages you show are probably irrelevant.)  Reformulate your example, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, so that it produces the problem you describe, so that helpers can compile it.

Comment: I have added the relevant part please

Comment: You haven't specified any positioning options for your figure.  The default assumption is that a float will appear at the top of a page, so that's what has most likely happened here.  Add the option `\begin{figure}[ht}` and if there is room "here", that's where it will be placed; if there's not room, it will move to the top of the next page.  There's lots of useful information about figure positioning in this question: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: note that the only reason to use `figure` is to take its content out of the main document flow and mark it as a float that may be re-inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking. So what you describe is the expected behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified any positioning options for your figure.  The default assumption is that a float will appear at the top of a page, so that's what has most likely happened here.

Add the option `\begin{figure}[ht}` and if there is room "here", that's where it will be placed; if there's not room, it will move to the top of the next page.

There's lots of useful information about figure positioning in this question: [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

As commented by David Carlisle, "the only reason to use `figure` is to take its content out of the main document flow and mark it as a float that may be re-inserted elsewhere to help with page breaking. So what you describe is the expected behaviour."